# How to change in Gradle time to live for artifact caches?

Tags: caching, gradle, snapshot, ttl

I am interested in reducing the time between refresh of SNAPSHOT versions of dependencies in Gradle.
How can I configure it and what is the default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapshots treated in Gradle as *changing modules*. By default, they are refreshed every 24 hours.
There is an explanation available on how to configure it in the Gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling-dynamic-version-caching)